# Get Image Resource Name of Control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, toolstripbutton

I have a Windows Form containing Toolstrip Buttons each having an image from Program Resource. During run time for some reasons want to find name of each image resource with C# code. Comparision like below does not return desired result:

```
if (ctrl.Image == Properties.Resources.MyResourceName)
{ //do logical operation...}
```

Comment: `Properties.Resources` is a Factory, it creates a new object each time, so the comparison with an existing object reference (you're comparing two references, not the content of the objects) always fails. Assign the images to Fields / Properties of a handler class / etc. beforehand (at run-time) to make the comparison work. You might succeed if you use `SequenceEquals()` to compare the content in bytes. I suggest you don't use that method anyway -- You could also set the name of the Resource to the `Tag` property of a Control (it's a hassle to maintain, though)